# Suppressed indices - when and why?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, tensor-calculus, notation, quantum-chromodynamics

When following textbooks in QFT I have many times seen the usage of 'suppressed indices'. This is a bit confusing to me, sometimes it is done without any explanation. For instance I usually see that spinor indices are suppressed in definitions of various Lagrangian densities.

Why are we sometimes omitting certain indices? Is it just to save time and space when writing equations or do the defined quantities mean different depending on if indices are suppressed or not?

One examples is the four-component spinor wave function $\psi_a(x)$, $a = 1,2,3,4$. It is usually just written in the suppressed form $\psi(x)$.

Comment: Typographical reasons (i.e. the formulas would be more involved, "fatter") mostly, even though the reasoning provided "officially" is different: we suppress them because the reader is smart enough to know they are there.

Answer (score 1):

> Why are we sometimes omitting certain indices? Is it just to save time and space when writing equations or do the defined quantities mean different depending on if indices are suppressed or not?

The former. When the latter applies, indices are either [contracted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation#Application) rather than suppressed, or absent because their presence indicates a derivative that might not be applied. Of course, a partial (covariant) derivative index is typically prefaced with a comma (semicolon).